# OOP - two tables into the same object

Tags: c#, oop

I have two tables in the database that are used almost for the same thing, but the tables don't have exactly the same structure.

Lets say I have one table for manual requests and another table for automatic requests. I have to load both tables into the same GridView and I'm using custom business objects.

To illustrate the question I'll call TManualReqTable and TAutomaticReqTable.

```
TManualReqTable 
- ID
- Field1
- Field2
- Field3
- Field4
```

and

```
TAutomaticReqTable
- ID
- Field1
- Field3
```

In the code, I'm using the same object for these two tables. I have an interface with all the properties of both tables and I'm checking if the field exists when I'm loading the data to the object.

But I'm thinking this should be created with two objects and one superclass with abstracts methods.

What is your opinion about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would create an interface `IRequest` that describes the fields &  methods common to both, and then interfaces & classes for `ManualRequest` and `AutomaticRequest` that implement `IRequest` and also add the methods/fields unique to each of them.

You can use `IRequest` as the type for something that incorporates either one. When iterating through something that can include data from either, you can check whether each object implements the interfaces:

```
foreach (IRequest obj in RequestList) {
  // do stuff that uses the common interface

  if (obj is IManualRequest) {
     // do stuff specific to manual requests
  } else if (obj is IAutomaticRequest) {
     // likewise
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I follow a general rule to avoid creating base classes unless:

1. I've already designed or discovered sufficient commonality to give sufficient substance to the base class.
2. I have a use case for consuming the classes as the base class; if I don't have anything that can operate on the common functionality of the classes, there's little value in having a base class (can achieve the same functionality through composition of a class implementing the common behaviors.)
3. The requirements are sufficiently stable that I believe the base class abstraction will hold without significant modification in the future.  Base classes become increasingly difficult to modify over time.

Answer (score 2):

IMO, forget how the database looks like for a minute or two.

1. Think of how it should be **structured** as an object.
2. Think of how you would like to **use** that object. If you need to visualize, write some code of that yet non-existing object and tweak it until it looks elegant.
3. Think of **how** to make it happen.

[model first development](http://www.google.ca/search?q=model%20first&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-GB%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#sclient=psy&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=3tI&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-GB%3aofficial&source=hp&q=model%20first%20development&aq=0&aqi=g1g-v3&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=92ca0954fc066d1c&biw=1280&bih=875)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

well, there are a few assumptions i'm making here, so let me make them explicit...

given:

1. this is primarily a difference in query/display logic
2. the display logic can already handle the nulls
3. the underlying object being represented is the same between the two items
4. there's a simple way of determining whether this was a 'manual' or an 'automatic' call

i would say that inheritance is not the way i would model it. why? because it's the same object, not two different kinds of object. you're basically just not displaying a couple of the fields, and therefore do not need to query them.

so, i would probably try to accomplish something that makes clear the nature of the difference between the two (keep in mind that i intend this to show a way of organizing it so that it's clear, any particular implementation might have different needs; the main idea to glean is treating the differences as what they are: differences in what gets queried based upon some sort of condition.

```
public enum EQueryMode
{
    Manual,
    Automatic
}

public class FieldSpecification
{
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public bool[] QueryInMode { get; set; }

    public FieldSpecification
        (
            string parFieldName, 
            bool parQueryInManual, 
            bool parQueryInAutomatic
        )
    {
        FieldName = parFieldName;
        QueryInMode = new bool[] { parQueryInManual, parQueryInAutomatic };
    }
}

public class SomeKindOfRecord
{
    public List<FieldSpecification> FieldInfo =
        new List<FieldSpecification>()
            {
                new FieldSpecification("Field1",  true, true),
                new FieldSpecification("Field2",  true, false),
                new FieldSpecification("Field3",  true, true),
                new FieldSpecification("Field4",  true, false)
            };

    // ...

    public void PerformQuery(EQueryMode QueryMode)
    {
        List<string> FieldsToSelect =
            (
                from f
                    in FieldInfo
                where
                    f.QueryInMode[(int)QueryMode]
                select
                    f.FieldName
            )
            .ToList();

        Fetch(FieldsToSelect);
    }

    private void Fetch(List<string> Fields)
    {
        // SQL (or whatever) here
    }
}
```

edit: wow i can't seem to make a post today without having to correct my grammar! ;)